# Connect to Server Status in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I followed the steps listed here http://wolfpaulus.com/journal/mac/tomcat7 to install Tomcat on Mac and I started the server and it went to Tomat Localhost page. There is Server Status button in that page which I clicked on, it asks for user/pass and it doesn't let me in.  Is there more setups I need to do from this point?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `username, password and role` in order to access manager application.

Open the `tomcat-users.xml` under the `conf` folder and `<user/>` entry.

```
<tomcat-users>
     ...  
    <user name="admin" password="admin" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-script,admin"/>
</tomcat-users>
```